# why is my mod_rewrite redirect only working for the requested page and not it's necessary css, js files?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying my first steps with setting `mod_rewrite` to make the URLs of an application a little nicer.

I have a skinnable system, with skins being set through a *query parameter*, so any of the following links will trigger a specific skin to be loaded (and stored as a cookie):

```
www.example.com/index.html?skin=123
```

I'm trying to make nice looking entry links into the system, so I'm using this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)/$ /index.html?app=%1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

which seems to work correctly, so I'm loading the correct page on the following links:

```
 www.example.com/890/  =>  www.example.com/index.html?skin=890
```

However, only my initial page is correctly loaded, all CSS and JS files are still being requested from the wrong path `www.example.com/890/` vs. `www.example.com`

**Question:**
How can I rewrite all requested files (CSS, js, img...) to be correctly redirected excluding the `/890/` path? Also, is there a way to make my rewrite more generic, so that I can handle both

```
 www.example.com/890/         => www.example.com/index.html?skin=890
 www.example.com/890/foo.html => www.example.com/foo.html?skin=890
 www.example.com/890/bar.html => www.example.com/bar.html?skin=890
```

Thanks for shedding some light!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you've set it to only rewrite URIs that end in a slash. If you want it to also use anything that follows the slash, you need a bit more. Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)/$ /index.html?app=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.+)$ /$1?app=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The second rule says "if it contains a slash, then store everything up to the next slash in $1. Then ignore the slash. Everything that follows the second slash should be stored in $2."

`www.mysite.com/foo/` will be caught by the first rewrite rule and rewritten to `www.mysite.com/index.html?skin=foo`

`www.mysite.com/foo/whatever.html` will be caught by the second rewrite rule and rewritten to `www.mysite.com/whatever.html?skin=foo`

Comment: ah. Very nice. Thanks! I also saw that I forgot the leading backslash on my pages, so changing from `<script data-main="js/main.js" type="..." src="js/require.js"></script>` to `<script data-main="/js/main.js" type="..." src="/js/require.js"></script>` solved my other question. Merci.

Comment: I would suggest you use ^/([^/]+)/(.+)$ for the second rewriterules' pattern. Otherwhise someting like /foo/bar/index.html will be rewritten als /index.html?skin=foo/bar which is probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: The backreference in the first rule, should be `$1`, not `%1`. If the "skin id" is always numeric (as per the examples in the question) then be more specific with the regex and match digits only. eg. `/(\d+)/` - this will help to avoid potential conflicts with other directives/URLs.

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo @MrWhite